InteractivePopGestureRecognizer is disabled after push to a UIHostingController with SwiftUI
I have pushed an UIHostingController which contains SwiftUI and set the navigationBar hidden:
class CoverVC : UIHostingController<AnyView>{
    
    public init(shouldShowNavigationBar: Bool, rootView: ICloudSyncView) {
        super.init(rootView: AnyView(rootView.navigationBarHidden(!shouldShowNavigationBar)))
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
    }
    
    @objc required dynamic init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension CoverVC: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

But the InteractivePopGestureRecognizer is disabled.
How can I to solve this?
